# How do I programmatically refund using paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

working on my paypal integration and its going great - I was wondering that in the case a refund needs to be made is there a way to have a refund made programmatically?

Comment: Here is an article for the refunding through php api. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/05/paypal-refund-transaction/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my understanding, you should use the Refund API.

- [Refund using SOAP](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_RefundTransaction)
- [Refund using NVP](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction)

Comment: links are not working anymore. they're pointing to the homepage

Answer (score 7):

Doing a refund in PayPal is straight forward if you follow the API documentation mentioned by Machine.

You may also find, if you prefer to save money, that you can Void a transaction in PayPal, before it is captured (usually before midnight on the day of the transaction), which is free.

I have found that always sending a void first, then if the void fails, sending the refund works well without much overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code of refund with NAP:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_php.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can find all sample-code here: 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

-- Jarnail

Comment: FYI: the link has gone stale.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code of refund with *NVP:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_php.txt

-- Jarnail

Answer (score 1):

you can find complete detail of refund transaction from here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link