# Paypal IPN verified. What to do if I need to refound?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm selling from my php site and I accept paypal payments, I've got a limited number of products, buyers have them in their carts, and availability is not enough for them all.
If they pay with paypal at the same time I need to refound one of them.
Is this approach correct, or is it preferable to check availability before the payment IPN notification?

Comment: I assume this is for Payments Standard. Correct?

Comment: @Machavity Yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a poor user flow. Once you get verification that an item is sold, reduce your inventory in your database. Before sending them to Paypal, verify that you have enough inventory to fulfill their order.

If you get a scenario where say you have one item left and two users were directed to Paypal to purchase it, whoever you receive notification of successful payment first, gets it. The other, you can do a few things:

1. Place the item on backorder, let the user know when it'll come in with an estimate. When it comes in, send it to them.
2. Allow the user to choose whether they want the backorder, or to cancel their order, in which case they get a refund
3. If, once a product sells out, there are none left forever, you can immediately issue a refund.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My specific scenario would be number 3. Do you know if a refund will have a fee to pay to paypal and where I can find a php example?

Comment: @kiks73 - Information about their refund API can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964274/how-do-i-programmatically-refund-using-paypal). I'm not sure about the fees, however unless your site is receiving a lot of traffic, its unlikely that you will hit this case very often. You could always send an email to yourself when it happens, and manually issue the refund through your Paypal account.